# Python: How to run flask mysqldb on Windows machine?

Tags: python, windows, flask, mysql-python

I've installed the `flask-mysqldb` module with pip package management system on my `Windows machine` and I don't know how to run it.

I have tried to add the path to the MySQLdb in System properties and still nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I work with Flask and MySQL in Windows, I use [XAMPP that includes MariaDB, PHP, and Perl](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html). I run the `XAMPP` server and start MySQL service.

I use [Flask-MySQL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-MySQL/) which can be installed using `pip install Flask-MySQL`.

Then I create database from `phpMyAdmin` which comes with `XAMPP`. In Flask app, I declare the connection and manipulate the database.

Here is a demonstration of how to use Flask with MySQL in this Python file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'matrimony'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/create_table', methods=['POST'])
def create_table():
    if request.method=="POST":
        try:
            table_name = request.form.get('table_name')
            field_name_list = request.form.getlist('fields[]')
            field_list = []
            for field in field_name_list:
                field_list.append(field+ " VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL")
            field_query = " ( " + ", ".join(field_list) + " ) "
            create_table_query = 'CREATE TABLE `'+table_name+'`' + field_query
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(create_table_query)
            return "Table: "+table_name+" created successfully"
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

In this example, I created MySQL table from user input with user mentioned column names.