# Failed to install flask-mysqldb

Tags: python, flask, pip

I am new in python and I'm trying to install **flask_mysqldb** from console. After attempting to install with PIP I'm getting this error:

```
Command "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u_90tj5p\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kdrtt5v6\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u_90tj5p\mysqlclient\
```

I have followed this one  [Flask-MySQLdb’s documentation][1]

what is this error? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

following might be the reason for the failure.

1) incompatible python issue,so install python 64 bit version instead of python 32
   or the other way and try to pip install again.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried, and  there is no improvement

Comment: another way is to download the wheel file and do pip install <path-of-.whl file> https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: or try https://pypi.org/project/Flask-MySQLdb/#files . here is the similar issues posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015590/python-how-to-run-flask-mysqldb-on-windows-machine

Comment: and even download mysqlclient from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: and also the error is because of mysql_client , so install the different version first https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/1.3.12/#files

Comment: similar issue found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146117/installing-mysqlclient-in-python-3-6-in-windows hope this will be helpful

Comment: glad to hear...which steps did u follow?

Comment: I reinstalled python 64, installaled visual studio code 64, then I installed windows SDK.[link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). then pip install MySQL, and pip install flask_mysqldb